# R package - binary (tar.gz)

Tags: r, r-package

Do we need to create tar.gz on a particular OS? e.g. if we create tar.gz on windows and copy it to Linux then will it work?

I am getting some error on Linux while code is working fine on Windows.

**create a package using below command (on the Window)**

```
devtools::build()
```

**During development on Windows**

```
file.sources = list.files(c("<path to R code>", 
                      pattern="*.R$", full.names=TRUE, 
                      ignore.case=TRUE)
sapply(file.sources,source,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Does the package contain compiled code? What is the error? How did you created the `tar.gz`? Please provide more information and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: added additional detail as above

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. binary files are platform-specific. tar.gz created on windows and then copied to Linux might give an unexplainable error.